# How important is it for Superman to see the light of day?

Tags: dc, superman, character-development, powers

As we all know, Superman is supposed to get his super powers from Earth's yellow Sun. It almost sounds like he needs exposure to daylight every so often to keep them.

How important is it for Superman to see the light of day?

Comment: @Obie2.0 Nice. I missed that one.